# Square div at center of the page of max size with pure css

Tags: css

I would like to achieve something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/e1c2tLme, but I need a `div` instead of the image.

**Square != rectangular**

Here is the working example: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Grief/7y93v1ch/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#b {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @ThomasOrlita many things but they didn't move me to the desired result. With the padding-top trick I can make the div square but its size would depend on the width of the page, not on the height

Comment: CSS can't do this...you need Javascript.

Comment: It cant be done in css mate

Comment: Why are you so sure? As I said, I am not a css specialist, so this is just a curiosity.

Comment: What would you guys say now? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4j8haquw/4/)

You can do it using [`vmin`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) unit.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
   background-color: #AAAAAA;
   width: 100vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">  
    Stuff goes here...
    </div>
</div>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#:%7E:text=axis.-,vmin,-Equal)

Comment: Square doesn't occupy all height when viewport is low but wide and scrollbar appears when viewport thin but tall

Comment: Oh, that looks pretty the same as result at which I stuck :) Please try to make the width of the viewport small and you will see that there is no square anymore. It works correct when width >= height, but not when width < height

Comment: I think I saw the comment from you, but you've removed it. Anyway, it was almost correct, so I'll accept your answer and update the question with the link to the solution soon. Stay tuned! The most import is to use `vmin` instead of `vh`!

Comment: I experimented 10 minutes on jsfiddle with that and found when I use `vmin` that works and now I look at SO and you wrote it... :)